# Derivatives of real part of function

Tags: derivatives, complex-numbers

My physics textbook gives me the complex form equation of simple harmonic motion as: $$z = Ae^{i(\omega _{o}t+\phi )}$$ and then defines $$ x = Re (z) $$

From there they argue that $$  \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = Re  \frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$$
and then they go on to state that:  $$ \frac{\partial Z}{\partial t} = i\omega _oz $$  Can someone explain how they are going from the 3rd equation to the 4th equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually directly from the first equation.$$z = Ae^{i(\omega _{o}t+\phi )} = Ae^{i\phi}e^{i\omega _{o}t}$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = i\omega _oAe^{i\phi}e^{i\omega _{o}t} = i\omega_{o} z $$

Comment: Ah.. That makes sense when you write it out like that.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: No , they wrote $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = Re  \frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$, which is different.